# FTP Username and Password on Parallel Panel

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I have taken space for a website using Parallel Panel,i am transferring my files using Filezilla ,but unable to login into it ,probably because of wrong credentials...how we can get username and password from parallel panel for ftp login?? Unable to find any options for the same..

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this files:

> C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\recentservers.xml
>   
> or
>   C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\sitemanager.xml

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you'll need to use something like winSCP to login securely.